# Do quiet induction burners exist?

Tags: equipment, induction

I've owned and used a variety of counter top induction burners, ranging from 1200-1800 watts, including popular, well reviewed brands.

Between the electronic whines and the fans, they were all extremely loud; amongst the loudest items in my home kitchen, and annoying enough that I don't use induction as much as I'd prefer to.

Do any quiet induction burners actually exist?

Comment: I've only ever used one once, and I don't remember it making loud noises ... but different people hear sounds at different frequencies.  (there was a thing years ago where teenagers were using high frequency noises for ring tones, as most older teachers couldn't hear them ... supposedly most people lose their high-range hearing with age.  Malls were also found to be using high-frequency noise to try to keep teens from loitering : https://www.cbsnews.com/news/high-pitched-device-drives-away-teens/ )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quieter, yes.  Quiet, no.

This was based on my recent research where I tested out 8 different portable induction burners, did a lot of reading, and ultimately decided not to buy one.

Induction burners [make noise](https://inductionpros.com/induction-cooktop-noise-level/) for two main reasons:

1. They work via a spinning electromagnetic field, which causes both the burner and the vessel to vibrate microscopically, creating a loud hum.
2. They have an internal fan to keep the electronics cool while the burner is on.  This is often the louder source of noise.

Higher-end induction burners produce less noise by having a heavier case (reducing vibration), and by having a better cooling fan. However, having tried some of these fairly expensive [commercial burners](https://www.magneticcooky.com/commercial-double-induction-cooktop-comparison/), like a Waring and a Vollrath, I'd say they are quieter but not exactly something you'd use in a room with a sleeping baby.

Built-in burners can reduce noise further simply by having sound insulation built into the cooktop, and many do.

Comment: Was the noise your primary reason for not buying, or were there other major contributing factors?

Comment: Are home ranges quiet enough? I've never been around one to know.

Comment: Oh my major reason was that I found out that most of my cookware, even the steel stuff, wouldn't work with them.  But the noise definitely didn't help.

Comment: I presume like the portable burners, it depends a lot on quality/price.  I've only tried two induction home ranges, and one was a prototype, so I can't offer specific feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this YouTube review of an Anko (Kmart Australia) and Ikea Tillreda portable induction cooktop, and the Tillreda was much quieter.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bk_Qa1uOSoY

If you have a gas cooktop and a noisy range hood like me, the fan noise of an induction cooktop will be much quieter.